# Recover the user that have been deleted

Tags: users

I have deleted some users, and now I want to recover onen of them. But I have a mesage that the user name and his email already exist.

Comment: do you have direct access to your database? mysql? phpmyadmin?

Comment: @woony. yes I have

Comment: Really I see that the username still exists in DB. But in wordpress I dont see it.

Comment: I would like to add a WARNING: Deleting Users within WordPress can result in pages/posts getting deleted that the user created. Just recovered a client's website from such a data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Users section in the WP back end and type in the username that exists. You should find a record if it is still there.

Deleting users completely deletes them - there is no "trash" normally, so the user should no longer exist in the database unless you have a plugin which keeps them.